# Why performance slows down a lot on amazon ec2?

Tags: java, performance, amazon-ec2

Not going into details of my algorithm, just giving some experiment results. For some given input, my Java sequential algorithm works 4 seconds on my laptop (Intel Core i5 430M - 2 cores, 4 threads, 2.27 GHz, 4Mb cache, 3Gb memory). Parallel version of the algorithm works 6 seconds using 1 thread, 5 seconds using 2 threads and 4 seconds using 3 threads. If I run it on amazon ec2 via ssh, time is 6 seconds for sequential and between 6 and 7 for parallel no matter how many threads.

Why do you think it is slower? Because amazon uses virtual machines and code running there is slower? What is your experience?

I have an application that I want to test in environments with lots of memory and computing power. Currently it is unsuccessful on amazon.

I use plain Java Objects and `hppc` external library (high performance primitive computing library). No databases and fancy stuff.

Instance type is c1, maybe this one (I will let you know soon if it correct, I know that it is c1, but do not know if it is medium or large):

```
High-CPU Extra Large Instance
7 GiB of memory
20 EC2 Compute Units (8 virtual cores with 2.5 EC2 Compute Units each)
1690 GB of instance storage
64-bit platform
I/O Performance: High
EBS-Optimized Available: 1000 Mbps
API name: c1.xlarge
```

Comment: What [instance type](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) are you using?

Comment: My experience is that virtual machines don't always scale the way you think they should.  Don't answer your question though. It doesn't appear your algorithim scales particularly well in any case i.e. using  3x threads gives you a 50% increase in performance.

Comment: Are you doing any disk I/O?

Comment: Disk IO to HDD is often slower with more threads.

Comment: Sounds like reasonable performance characteristics if the OS has only found one core. Otherwise, as others have said, it may be caused by I/O which - in my experience - can be _quite_ slow at EC2.

Comment: Sounds like its time to break out a java profiler...  :-)

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, virtual machines have very expensive mutltithread task switching penalties that can cause severe performance penalties if:

1. your threads have a lot of inter-thread communication, and
2. there are multiple VMs running on a single physical machine.

Virtual machine "cores" are actually mapped as threads onto the physical machine's master operating system.  If the master OS has a thread quantum of 30ms and the VM also has a thread quantum of 30ms, then what can happen is:

1. the VM will try "wake up" a sleeping thread on one of its virtual cores.
2. that sends a signal to the hardware OS to wake up a thread on a physical core.
3. Another VM is using them.  Wait 30ms for quantum.
4. Thread wakes up on HW.

If your other thread was expecting a response a bit quicker than 30ms, then you've got yourself a bottleneck.  To make matters worse, the default quantum for non-idle thread scheduling on Linux-based servers is actually ~100ms.

Amazon EC2 systems are not just virtual machines, they are virtual machines *sharing* a single physical machine.  To get the most bang/buck per server rack, Amazon must furthermore over-subscribe the systems to some extent.  Ex:

- Physical host has 16 HT threads (8 physical cores)
- VMs have 8 virtual cores each
- EC2 will stick 3-4 VMs on the machine (over-subscribed)

This is done because a lot of apps don't use full load of 8 cores.  But if you're paired with something that is using a full 8 cores then.. bummer!  I'm not sure what the actual pairing ratios are, and I imagine Amazon's constantly tweaking it anyway.